# How to define a generic property that conforms to a protocol

Tags: ios, swift

Sorry for the somewhat vague question title, but I'm not exactly sure what a more appropriate title would be.

Let me start by explaining my setup and what I'm trying to achieve.

I have defined an interface called `DeviceInterface`. I have two objects that conform to that interface: a mocked object called `MockedDevice` and the actual implementation object called `DeviceImplementation`.

The plan is to use `MockedDevice` for SwiftUI previews and for running the app in the simulator (where certain device actions/values are not available) and `DeviceImplementation` for on device execution.

The issues arises in `DeviceApp` where I instantiate the main app view with an object that conforms to `DeviceInterface`. I define a generic property of type `DeviceInterface` that I try to set based on whether the code is executing on the simulator or on the device.

When I try to pass that property to the main view of the app (`ContentView` that initializes with a generic type that conform to the interface `DeviceInterface`) I get the following error:

`Value of protocol type 'DeviceInterface' cannot conform to 'DeviceInterface'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols`

Initializing the property directly as
`let device = DeviceImplementation(device: UIDevice.current)`
or
`let device = MockedDevice(device: UIDevice.current)`
(by omitting the type) and then passing this value works totally fine, so it seems that my problem is in the type definition of the property.

I know I could just rearrange the code a bit and instantiate `ContentView` inside the `#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR` cases using the above working instantiation methods where I omit the type definition, but I want to understand what I'm doing wrong and how can I make the below code work.

See the following example for a demonstration of what I'm trying to achieve. Please keep in mind it's a quick and simple demonstration of the problem I'm tying to solve.

```
// MARK: - Interfaces

protocol DeviceInterface {
    var name: String { get }
}

protocol ObservableDevice: DeviceInterface, ObservableObject {}

// MARK: - Implementations

class MockedDevice: ObservableDevice {
    @Published
    var name: String  = ""
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class DeviceImplementation: ObservableDevice {
    @Published
    private(set) var name: String  = ""
    
    let device: UIDevice
    
    init(device: UIDevice) {
        self.device = device
        name = device.name
    }
}

// MARK: - App

@main
struct DeviceApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            let device: ObservableDevice = {
                #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
                return MockedDevice(name: "Mocked device")
                #else
                return DeviceImplementation(device: UIDevice.current)
                #endif
            }()
            
            ContentView(device: device) // Generates error: Value of protocol type 'DeviceInterface' cannot conform to 'DeviceInterface'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Main view

struct ContentView<T>: View where T: ObservableDevice {
    
    @ObservedObject
    private(set) var device: T
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
    
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let device = MockedDevice(name: "Mocked device")
        ContentView(device: device)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how DeviceImplementation and MockedDevice differ in practice? I there some reason that you can't just have a Device struct and initialize it with raw data or a UIDevice and get rid of the protocol entirely?

Comment: Also, can you describe why `ContentView` is generic rather than just having `var device: DeviceInterface`? The generic-ness doesn't seem to be doing anything here and just gets in the way. Is there a deeper problem that you're not describing in your example?

Comment: I'm planning on keeping it generic since in the iOS app I'm using UIDevice and on the watchOS app I'm using WKInterfaceDevice. I'm observing some notifications on either object so that's why I cannot just use a Device struct. And for the second question there actually is a reason I'm keeping it generic. I didn't include it since I didn't want to cause too much confusion but I guess I should. ContentView actually takes a type that conforms to `BatteryDeviceInterface, ObservableObject` and if I don't keep it generic I'm running into further errors. Let me update the question.

Comment: When you feel the need to add "Interface" or "Implementation" to the names of things, you've probably gone down a bad road already. :D

Comment: The ObservableObject piece is probably the most important piece of this. Until you said that, the solutions feel really obvious, but ObservableObject can be tricky.

Comment: I updated the example. As you said the ObservableObject is in fact the key to the above problem.

Comment: This still doesn't explain why `ContentView.device` isn't of type `ObservableDevice`. Making this generic dramatically complicates things, and I'm having trouble picturing the use case. Is the real point here to observe batteryLevel changes rather than name changes?

Comment: Removing the genericness of ContentView and defining ContentView.device as ObservableDevice triggers another error: `Property type 'ObservableDevice' does not match that of the 'wrappedValue' property of its wrapper type 'ObservedObject'`. I'm totally new to SwiftUI and ObservableDevice.

Comment: But I take it that "MockedDevice" still really isn't what you care about. It's UIDevice vs WKInterfaceDevice, right? And you want to track the battery, correct? (This matters because this all can be much simpler if you just abstract the observations rather than trying to create mocks, which is the answer I'll write up).

Comment: Yes you are correct:)

Comment: Honestly I don't care about MockedDevice at all. I just wanted to pass a mocked object for simulator usage. It's not that important. The reason I posted the question is just because I wanted to understand how to fix the above issue. This is just an exercise app for SwiftUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, how I'd really do this: subclassing. You already have a class, and the "abstract" version is precisely your "mock" version. So I'd just keep going and make a subclass:

```
// "Abstract" version (just set the values and they never change)
class Device: ObservableObject {
    @Published
    fileprivate(set) var name: String

    @Published
    fileprivate(set) var batteryLevel: Float

    init(name: String = "", batteryLevel: Float = -1) {
        self.name = name
        self.batteryLevel = batteryLevel
    }
}

// Self-updating version based on UIKit. Similar version could be made for WatchKit
class UIKitDevice: Device {
    private var token: NSObjectProtocol?

    init(device: UIDevice) {
        super.init(name: device.name, batteryLevel: device.batteryLevel)

        device.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
        token = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIDevice.batteryLevelDidChangeNotification, 
                                                       object: device,
                                                       queue: nil) { [weak self] _ in
            self?.batteryLevel = device.batteryLevel
        }
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(token!)
    }
}
```

Then the `device` definition is:

```
        let device: Device = {
            #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
            return Device(name: "Mocked device")
            #else
            return UIKitDevice(device: .current)
            #endif
        }()
```

Easy. I like it.

---

But I'm not a huge fan of subclassing in Swift. In this case it works fine, but in general inheritance is not a great thing IMO. So how would you do this with composition rather than inheritance?

First, abstract a thing that can update the battery information:

```
import Combine // For Cancellable

protocol BatteryUpdater {
    func addBatteryUpdater(update: @escaping (Float) -> Void) -> Cancellable
}
```

And accept a BatteryUpdater to Device (marking `final` just to prove I can; I don't advocate sprinkling `final` all over the place):

```
final class Device: ObservableObject {
    @Published
    private(set) var name: String

    @Published
    private(set) var batteryLevel: Float

    private var batteryObserver: Cancellable?

    init(name: String = "", batteryLevel: Float = -1, batteryUpdater: BatteryUpdater? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.batteryLevel = batteryLevel

        batteryObserver = batteryUpdater?.addBatteryUpdater(update: { [weak self] level in
            self?.batteryLevel = level
        })
    }

    deinit {
        batteryObserver?.cancel()
    }
}
```

So now Device just holds data normally, but it can ask for its battery level to be updated by something else. And it can cancel that request. I could also have used KeyPaths here, or other fancier Combine tools, but this shows the idea. Abstract away the thing that changes, which is "how does the battery value get changed." Don't abstract away the thing that doesn't change, which is "I have a battery level and notify observers when it changes."

With this in place, behold the power of retroactive conformance. UIDevice can be a BatteryUpdater:

```
extension UIDevice: BatteryUpdater {
    func addBatteryUpdater(update: @escaping (Float) -> Void) -> Cancellable {
        let nc = NotificationCenter.default
        let token = nc.addObserver(forName: UIDevice.batteryLevelDidChangeNotification,
                                   object: self, queue: nil) { _ in
            // This retains self as long as the observer exists. That's intentional
            update(self.batteryLevel)
        }

        return AnyCancellable {
            nc.removeObserver(token)
        }
    }
}
```

And a convenience initializer makes it easy to create from a UIDevice:

```
extension Device {
    convenience init(device: UIDevice) {
        self.init(name: device.name, batteryLevel: device.batteryLevel, batteryUpdater: device)
    }
}
```

And now creating the Device looks like this:

```
        let device: Device = {
            #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
            return Device(name: "Mocked device")
            #else
            return Device(device: .current)
            #endif
        }()
```

It's just always a Device. No mocks. No protocol existentials. No generics.

---

What if there are more things to update than just BatteryLevel? It could get annoying to keep passing more and more closures. So you could instead turn BatteryUpdater into a full DeviceUpdater by passing the whole Device:

```
protocol DeviceUpdater {
    func addUpdater(for device: Device) -> Cancellable
}
```

Device is basically the same, just adding proximityState to have something else to update:

```
final class Device: ObservableObject {
    @Published
    private(set) var name: String

    @Published
    fileprivate(set) var batteryLevel: Float

    @Published
    fileprivate(set) var proximityState: Bool

    private var updateObserver: Cancellable?

    init(name: String = "", batteryLevel: Float = -1, proximityState: Bool = false,
         updater: DeviceUpdater? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.batteryLevel = batteryLevel
        self.proximityState = proximityState

        updateObserver = updater?.addUpdater(for: self)
    }

    deinit {
        updateObserver?.cancel()
    }
}
```

And UIDevice conforms about the same way, just kind of "inside out" by directly updating `device`.

```
extension UIDevice: DeviceUpdater {
    func addUpdater(for device: Device) -> Cancellable {

        let nc = NotificationCenter.default
        let battery = nc.addObserver(forName: UIDevice.batteryLevelDidChangeNotification,
                                   object: self, queue: nil) { [weak device] _ in
            device?.batteryLevel = self.batteryLevel
        }

        let prox = nc.addObserver(forName: UIDevice.proximityStateDidChangeNotification,
                                   object: self, queue: nil) { [weak device] _ in
            device?.proximityState = self.proximityState
        }

        return AnyCancellable {
            nc.removeObserver(battery)
            nc.removeObserver(prox)
        }
    }
}
```

That does force the properties to be non-private. You could fix that by passing WritableKeyPaths, if you wanted. Lots of approaches can work. But all follow the pattern of abstracting the updating rather than mocking the final data storage.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for such an in depth answer. To be honest my question wasn't about how would I observe the device battery (it is true that is what I'm doing) but I wanted a general solution for what I'm doing wrong for the exact case I described. I guess I just put together a weird scenario that doesn't really have a clear answer. Your answer solves my problem but doesn't explain how to fix exactly the issue I described, but just out of respect for the amount of time put into the answer, I'm accepting it as the accepted answer. Thank you!!

Comment: My experience in Swift is the more general or abstract the question, the less likely there is any satisfying answer. Swift has a very powerful type system with some very sharp edges where it suddenly "just can't do that." On the other hand, problems in the form "I want to solve this specific code duplication problem in this specific program" generally (though not always) have pretty solid solutions. The real answer to your original question is "you can't." But that answer is boring, so I've been trying to use that answer less often. :)

Comment: Yeah I totally get what you mean. I was kind of expecting that the answer would be "you can't" but I still wanted to see what has stack overflow to offer:) Thank you very much for not just giving the boring you "can't do that answer" and instead thinking of the creative one. Appreciate it! :)